# Как получить имя файла из URL?

Tags: java

Хочу получить имя файла по ссылке вроде такой:

```
http://localhost:7070/file.tar.gz
```

Пробовал с помощью класса `URI`, но не могу найти необходимый для этого метод...

Comment: [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605696/get-file-name-from-url)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно вот так

```
Paths.get("http://localhost:7070/file.tar.gz").getFileName()
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d97ab4b306d67c6fa7b5c2d3e7589108

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Program
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Path path = Paths.get("http://localhost:7070/file.tar.gz");
    System.out.println(path);
    System.out.println(path.getFileName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Как выяснилось, метод не работает под Windows: [Ошибка чтения пути paths.get() java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160709/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-paths-get-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Если специальные классы не подходят, то можно регуляркой:

```
[^\/]*$
```

Тролько надо добавить экранирование по необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

У класса `URL` есть метод `getFile()`.

Но если посмотреть глубже, внутрь класса `URL`, то можно увидеть что внутренний объект `file` в `URL` устанавливается так:

```
this.file = query == null ? path : path + "?" + query;
```

То есть по сути это все что следует в URL после слеша, следующего за портом.
Если у вас будет такой URL: `http://localhost:7070/foo/bar/file.tar.gz`, то `getFile()` вернет `foo/bar/file.tar.gz`. Если вам нужно именно `file.tar.gz`, то остается искать последний слеш (`lastIndexOf`) и брать подстроку, либо же прикрутить [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), как рекомендуют по ссылке в комментарии под вашим вопросом.