# Ошибка чтения пути paths.get() java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

получаю вот такую ошибку при использовании paths. Ссылку получаю из БД postgre. Не могу понять, что не так с ссылкой.

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: http://localhost:8080/download/2QkQNYMM84w.jpg
```

Вот сам код.

```
 @PostMapping("/update-picture")
    @ResponseStatus
    public FileResponse updatePicture(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        UserEntity user = userService.findByLogin(jwtProvider.getLoginFromToken(request.getHeader("Authorization")));
        Path path = Paths.get(user.getUrl_picture().trim());
        storageService.delete(path.getFileName().toString());
        return uploadFile(multipartFile,request);

    }
```

Comment: А что должен делать этот код? `Path` работает с файловой системой, он не выкачает файл из интернета.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605761/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, [трюк с `Paths.get`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605761/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url#605831) для получения имени файла из адреса работает не везде. Под Windows, класс, отвечающий за файловую систему, `sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser` проверяет, что в пути указан максимум один однобуквенный диск в начале строки и что в остальной строке нет двоеточия.

Не рекомендую усугублять ситуацию и пытаться подстроить веб-адрес под требования `Paths.get`. Лучше выберите другой способ определения имени файла. Множество таких способов можно найти в таком же вопросе на английском: [Get file name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605696/get-file-name-from-url).

Самый популярный ответ предлагает подключить [Apache Commons (commons-io)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/):

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(user.getUrl_picture().trim());
storageService.delete(filename);
```

Вроде бы это работает, хотя `FilenameUtils` тоже предназначен для файловой системы. Протестируйте повнимательнее случай адресов с GET параметрами.

**Дополнение:** «Хорошего» класса, предназначенного именно для URL, решающего эту задачу, я так сразу не нашел. Если `FilenameUtils` по каким-то причинам не сработает, то можно пойти на крайние меры, а именно на регулярное выражение:

```
/**
* Регулярное выражение для выделения имени файла из URL.
* <p>
* Найдено на
* <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473180/regex-to-get-a-filename-from-a-url#26253039">Stack
* Overflow</a>
* <p>
* Разбор:
* <ul>
* <li>[^/\\&\?]+ - имя файла (любой набор символов кроме /, \, & и ?)
* <li>.\\w{1,5} - расширение (от одной до пяти букв)
* <li>(?=([\?&].*$|$)) - проверка что после файла либо конец строки, либо
* GET-параметры.
* </ul>
*/
private static final Pattern FILENAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^/\\\\&\\?]+\\.\\w{1,5}(?=([\\?&].*$|$))");

/**
* Выделяет имя файла из URL
*
* @param path - строка URL
* @return имя файла
*/
private static String getFilename(String path) {
    Matcher matcher = FILENAME_PATTERN.matcher(path);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't find a filename in a path: " + path);
    }
    return matcher.group();
}
```